# Узнать url вкладок, запущенных в браузерах

Tags: c#

Что бы узнать url активной вкладки, нужно использовать этот код

```
 var roots = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "Chrome_WidgetWin_1"));
    foreach (AutomationElement root in roots)
    {
        var textP = root.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit));
        var vpi = textP.GetCurrentPropertyValue(ValuePatternIdentifiers.ValueProperty);
        Console.WriteLine(vpi);
    }
```

Но его главный минус, то что он сильно нагружает ЦП. А если узнавать url каждые 10-30 секунд, то этот способ сильно не подходит.

С Selenium WebDriver не может работать уже с запущенными браузерами.

Есть какой-нибудь оптимизированный метод, чтобы узнать url активной вкладки, или вообще все запущенные url?
Желательно кроссплатформенный, но если есть способ с WinAPI, то он тоже подойдет

Answer (score -1):

Если у вас Enterprise версия студии то вы можете использовать Coded UI.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866067/get-current-url-in-codedui